# Is it fine to use $http.post for all my requests in a mobile app?

Tags: php, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I am building a ionic app that interacts with my PHP backend. Each of my calls to the API are made with $http.post and I retrieve the data as json in my php scripts.

Is this fine or will this cause any problems for the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, as long as you consider the following things:

- sending everything as "POST" might confuse developers. Speaking in REST terms, POST is send when creating something new on the server. GET is used to read something. PUT is used to update. And so on. For some clean code, you might consider making a difference here
- What happens, if the user is offline? Is it a problem?
- How many requests are happening? Many requests slow down your application, as the user has to wait.

You can think about offline support, caching data on the smartphone and similar things. People nowadays expect things like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm. Your js code shoube be expressive and readable to other developers also. Use POST when you are writing or sending some information to the server.

Answer (score -1):

i don't think so, i have my ionic app with a lot of services with $http.post request and i still not having problems.

Maybe the only one that will have problems just your backend for overload or something like that but not your app.

So i think you can continue coding your app :)